# Node.js and/or npm is not installed when running "docker-compose up"

Tags: node.js, django, docker-compose, dockerfile, tailwind-css

I am trying to Dockerize a Django app with tailwind to deploy to lightsail.
I followed two tutorials. Their githubs are:
https://github.com/LondonAppDeveloper/tutorial-django-aws-lightsail
https://github.com/timonweb/django-tailwind

Both work individually. Now I am trying to combine the both. I started with the django-tailwind guide, then added the code from the first tutorial to it.

When I run docker-compose build it builds (19/28) of the commands, I assume.
When I run docker-compose up I get the error

```
gmo-django-lightsail-tailwind-1  | CommandError:
gmo-django-lightsail-tailwind-1  | It looks like node.js and/or npm is not installed or cannot be found.
gmo-django-lightsail-tailwind-1  |
gmo-django-lightsail-tailwind-1  | Visit https://nodejs.org to download and install node.js for your system.
gmo-django-lightsail-tailwind-1  |
gmo-django-lightsail-tailwind-1  | If you have npm installed and still getting this error message, set NPM_BIN_PATH variable in settings.py to match path of NPM executable in your system.
gmo-django-lightsail-tailwind-1  |
gmo-django-lightsail-tailwind-1  | Example:
gmo-django-lightsail-tailwind-1  | NPM_BIN_PATH = "/usr/local/bin/npm
```

In my settings.py I have "NPM_BIN_PATH = r"C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.cmd" included.

**Here is my Dockerfile:**

```
FROM python:3.11.1-alpine3.17

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

COPY ./requirements.txt /requirements.txt

RUN apk add --update --no-cache \
  postgresql-client \
  build-base \
  postgresql-dev \
  musl-dev \
  zlib \
  zlib-dev \
  linux-headers

WORKDIR /gmo

RUN apk add --no-cache \
  musl-dev \
  curl \
  nodejs

RUN python -m venv /py && \
  /py/bin/pip install --upgrade pip && \
  /py/bin/pip install -r /requirements.txt

COPY ./scripts /scripts

RUN chmod -R +x /scripts

ENV PATH="/scripts:/py/bin:$PATH"

COPY ./gmo /gmo

WORKDIR /gmo

EXPOSE 80

CMD ["/scripts/run.sh"]
```

**Here is my docker-compose file:**

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  gmo:
    build:
      context: .
    volumes:
      - ./gmo:/gmo
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    command: sh -c "python manage.py migrate && python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"
    environment:
      DEBUG: 1
      DB_HOST: database
      DB_NAME: django-dev-db
      DB_USER: devuser
      DB_PASS: devpassword123
    depends_on:
      database:
        condition: service_healthy

  tailwind:
    build:
      context: .
    volumes:
      - ./gmo:/gmo
    command: python manage.py tailwind start
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true

  database:
    image: postgres:12-alpine
    volumes:
      - dev-db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: django-dev-db
      POSTGRES_USER: devuser
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: devpassword123
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "pg_isready", "-q", "-d", "django-dev-db", "-U", "devuser"]
      interval: 5s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 10

volumes:
  dev-db-data:
```

**and here is my script file (run.sh):**

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e

SECRET_KEY=nothing python manage.py tailwind install --no-input
SECRET_KEY=nothing python manage.py tailwind build --no-input
SECRET_KEY=nothing python manage.py collectstatic --no-input
python manage.py migrate
gunicorn -b :80 --chdir /gmo gmo.wsgi:application
```

Well, I've tried many things. Editing the docker-compose and Dockerfile (the latest modification is posted).

I want to be able to live update tailwind when I run docker-compose up. It sometimes works, but then doesn't live update after. Normal HTML changes work, but tailwind specific changes doesn't.